# How to align enumerate and image

Tags: graphics, lists, vertical-alignment

I have the following code which doesn't align a) and b) with the top of the image. How can I align them?

```
...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find the unknown values and in each case, give a reason. 

  \begin{enumerate}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{images/image1.png}\\
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{images/image2.png}\\
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
...
```

[image]

Comment: the baseline of an image is its bottom edge, not its top. You could use `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{...}` or more simply use the facilities of the `adjustbox` package to change the baseline of the image.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A good question, but I think it has been asked before :) [What's the best way to include graphics in an enumerated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46230) or [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30367)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox` package with `export` option. Then a key `valign` is available inside `\includegraphics` for vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find the unknown values and in each case, give a reason.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{example-image-a}
\item
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{example-image-b}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]