# Including graphic in enumerate item causes overfull \hbox

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I just picked code from [What's the best way to include graphics in an enumerated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46230/whats-the-best-way-to-include-graphics-in-an-enumerated-list) to include a graphic in an enumerated list. But the code causes a overfull \hbox if I use it in the first enumeration item. How can I solve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
          \raggedright
          \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{E53a}%
          }
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Another MWE using `\linewidth` but still doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{
\section{Title}
}{\stepcounter{mycounter}}

\newtheorem{myth}{}[mycounter]

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\begin{myth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{E53a}%
\end{enumerate}
\end{myth}

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An overfull box is just a warning, if you think the output is ok then you can safely ignore the warning. That said, `width=\textwidth` within an `enumerate` is slightly too wide, you could try `width=0.9\textwidth` to make it fit better.

Comment: Hmm, I actually do not want to ignore the warning.

Comment: @Marijn there is no need to guess like that.

Comment: the line width in an indented list is `\linewidth` not `\textwidth`

Comment: ```\linewidth``` doesn't work either @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: unrelated but if you use the `export` option when loading adjustbox you can use teh nicer syntax `\includegraphics[valign=t]{...}` ratther than needing teh adjustbox wrapper (and you do  not need the `minipage `in any case.

Comment: yes `\linewidth` does work:-)  I posted some code as an answer

Comment: you are defining `myenv` to take an argument `#1` which it discards, so it is discarding the blank line hrere but if you didn't have a blank lien after `\begin` it would discard teh `\begin` or `\begin{myth}` is that the intended behaviour???

Comment: Of course not. The argument was only a leftover, thanks. But that does "unfortunately" not affect the overfull \hbox.

Comment: it's the usual wacky behaviour of an enumerate at the start of a theorem. If you add `\item zzz` after it you will see that the 2 is in the usual place then `\linewidth` will work but for the first item 1 is inlined after the  theorem heading so not in line with the other labels that's intentional in the latex code (but I never liked it:-) if you want that you need to account for the theorem heading o simply use `\begin{myth}\mbox{}` so the label  1. goes in line with 2. and then `\linewidth` is the right thing.

Comment: Is there no other, "right" way? That would work of course - but for consistency purposes I would highly appreciate a solution where the image could sit next to the label and not causing a badbox. Maybe I'm a bit difficult :o)

Answer (score 1):

You want `\linewidth` not `\textwidth` in an indented list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{E53a}%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

one way of tackling enumerate in a theorem is to make sure it isn't first (add `\mbox{}` if no actual text

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{%
\section{Title}%
}{\stepcounter{mycounter}}%


\newtheorem{myth}{}[mycounter]

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\begin{myth}\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{E53a}%
\item zzz
\end{enumerate}
\end{myth}

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird - it works in a dummy file but in my document, it is still ~32pt too wide (```\textwidth``` was ~60pt too wide). How can it come?

Comment: @Thomas start from your document where it is wrong and delete everything you can delete until you get a small enough example to add to your question.

Comment: I added another working non-working example including more of my document's structure.