# How to put pictures in an enumerated list (beside "minipage")?

Tags: graphics, lists

I would like to make an enumerated list with pictures below the text. Something like this

[image]

I have tried the `minipage` before, as mentioned in [What's the best way to include graphics in an enumerated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46230/295683). But the result seems not really what I want. Instead of putting the picture below the text, it put the picture beside the text, which is very annoying. Is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.stack. Please post your `preamble`, i.e., from `\documentclass to \end{document}`

Comment: @GowriSaro Thank you for reminding. This is my first post. I will do that in my future post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, in terms of achieving your formatting objective, whether or not you encase the image in a `minipage`. What's crucial is to *leave an empty line* between the `\item` line and the image/minipage code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Morlet wavelet

   \includegraphics{my_pic_1} % note the blank line before this line

\item Gabor wavelet

   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} % note the blank line before this line
   \includegraphics{my_pic_2}
   \end{minipage}

\item Mexican Hat wavelet

    \includegraphics{my_pic_3} % note the blank line before this line
    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```